# ViewPager returns wrong Object

Tags: android

The pager returns the 1st object in the array list, and keeps returning the 1st object even if i swing left and right, did a lot of debugging, and for some reason when the pager get's to `getItem(int position)` it start's going crazy, it **FINDS** the corresponding object , then looks a the previous object`(pos-1)` then does some other weird things and returns the 1st obj in `arrayList`.

This method is called within the ViewHolder of `RecyclerViewAdapter`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = ProductPageActivity.newIntent(v.getContext(),mProduct.getId());
    v.getContext().startActivity(i);
}
}
public class ProductFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "ProductFragment";
    private static final String ARGUMENT_PROD_ID = "prod_id";
    private TextView mTitle,mDesc,mImgUrl,mPrice;
    private List<Product> mProducts;
    private Product product;



    public static Fragment newInstance(UUID productID) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARGUMENT_PROD_ID,productID);
        ProductFragment frag = new ProductFragment();
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    public ProductFragment() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(getArguments() != null) {
            UUID id = (UUID) getArguments().getSerializable(ARGUMENT_PROD_ID);
            product = ProductHolder.get(getContext()).getProduct(id);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_fragment,container,false);
        setWidgets(v);
        setDataOnText();
        return v;
    }

    private void setDataOnText(){
        mTitle.setText(product.getTitle());
        mDesc.setText(product.getDesc());
        mPrice.setText(product.getPrice());
    }

    private void setWidgets(View v) {
        mTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        mDesc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        mPrice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.price);
    }
}

public class ProductPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String PRODUCT_ID = "com.example.cmd.testproject.Activitys.ProductPageActivity.product_id";
    private UUID productId;

    private ViewPager mPager;
    private List<Product> mProducts;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.product_page_activity);

        productId = (UUID) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(PRODUCT_ID);

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        mProducts = ProductHolder.get(this).getProducts();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                Product pr = mProducts.get(position);
                return ProductFragment.newInstance(pr.getId());
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mProducts.size();
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < mProducts.size(); i++) {
            if (mProducts.get(i).getId().equals(productId)) {
                mPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, UUID productID) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, ProductPageActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(PRODUCT_ID, productID);
        return intent;
    }
}

public class ProductHolder {
    private static final String TAG = "ProductHolder";
    private static ProductHolder sProductHolder;
    private List<Product> mProducts;

    public static ProductHolder get(Context ctx) {
        if(sProductHolder == null) {
            sProductHolder = new ProductHolder(ctx);
        }
        return sProductHolder;
    }

    private ProductHolder(Context ctx) {
            mProducts = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                Product product = new Product("Product = " + i, "Desc = "
                        + i, "ImgUrl = " + i, "Price = " + i + 2.2);
                mProducts.add(product);
            }
    }

    public Product getProduct(UUID prodId) {
        for (Product pr:mProducts) {
            if(pr.getId().equals(prodId));
            return pr;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return mProducts;
    }
}
```

Comment: when you debug do you get ARGUMENT_PROD_ID correct ID?

Comment: @AmodGokhale yes the id is the currect one i will tell you what it does.

Comment: @AmodGokhale yes it is , it finds the correct Product,sets it, goes to find it's position in getItem(int pos) , finds it, then it returns a new instance of fragment,then it goes to the start of the method, sets the position of current object in the ProductsList to -1, returns a object in that position,then goes back to start of method, goes to its original position and returns it and i still get the 1st product in ProductList

Comment: instead of inline fragmentStatePagerAdapter. Create a separate static fragmentStatePagerAdper as shown in this example https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html  Rest of code looks good.. only difference i find is setting adapter